# Unable to locate the source file. Please check your path

Tags: php, codeigniter, ftp

I have tried to upload a file using codeigniter ftp class.

```
$this->load->library('ftp');

    $config['hostname'] = 'www.domain.com';

    $config['username'] = 'xxxxxxxxx';

    $config['password'] = 'xxxxxxxx';

    $config['port']     = 21;

    $config['passive']  = FALSE;

    $config['debug']    = TRUE;

    $this->ftp->connect($config);

    $this->ftp->upload('C:\Users\SYSTEM2\Desktop\checking\ash.jpg\' ,  base_url().'uploads/myfolder/ash.jpg/');

    $this->ftp->close();
```

but showing this error

"Unable to locate the source file. Please check your path."
anybody please help me to solve this problem...

Comment: I'm amazed you're not getting a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Instead this

```
$this->ftp->upload('C:\Users\SYSTEM2\Desktop\checking\ash.jpg\' ,  base_url().'uploads/myfolder/ash.jpg/');
```

use

```
 $this->ftp->upload('C:\Users\SYSTEM2\Desktop\checking\ash.jpg','/www/uploads/myfolder/ash.jpg');
```

But you should know the root path in your ftp server, sometimes it "/www/yourdomen/".

Comment: $fname = 'C:\\Users\\SYSTEM2\\Desktop\\checking\\ash.jpg';
   if (file_exists($fname)) {
       $this->ftp->upload($fname, '/www/public/myfolder/ash.jpg');
   } else {
       echo 'File not found!';
   }                                                 output:-"File not found!"

Comment: The error has always been the SOURCE file (as clearly stated), don't know why everyone keeps suggesting new DESTINATION paths

Comment: Maybe your wrote incorrect path to ash.jpg in windows? Try to click on file ash.jpg, select "Properties" and see "Location" param

Comment: "C:\Users\SYSTEM2\Desktop\checking" i got this

Comment: $fname = "C:\Users\SYSTEM2\Desktop\checking\ash.jpg";
   if (file_exists($fname)) {    
    echo "file exists";
       } else {
       echo 'File not found!';
   } in localhost it results "file exists". after uploading it results file not found.

Comment: As I know You want to remote server take the file ash.jpg from your pc and download it to remote folder /uploads ?

Comment: yes Andrei I want to upload file from my pc to remote folder public/myfolder

Comment: Ok. I got it. But you should know what remote server nothing "know" about your local path and your PC)). The solution is organize the local web-server like you have now and use script on local machine or make public folder on your PC what must be seen from internet. The second is more complicated

Answer (score 1):

Try `$this->ftp->upload('C:/Users/SYSTEM2/Desktop/checking/ash.jpg' ,  '/www/uploads/myfolder/');` it is working for me best of luck

Comment: my problem is with source file location. When i check file_exists('C:/Users/SYSTEM2/Desktop/checking/ash.jpg'). it returns false. Can you please tell me what is the problem with my source file.  i am sure in my pc that file exists. Then why it says 'Unable to locate the source file'.

Comment: make sure ash.jpg exists in C:/Users/SYSTEM2/Desktop/checking/ other wise it will return false.

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter ftp class check if the file exists first then perform the upload you take a look at the code in codeigniter folder **system\libraries\FTP.php** line 238

```
if ( ! file_exists($locpath))
{
 $this->_error('ftp_no_source_file');
 return FALSE;
}
```

According to [php.net](https://www.php.net/file_exists) site you local file path should be in the form //computername/share/filename if you use file_exists with local files outside your web server.

which means you must put the file in a shared folder with public permissions.

if you set that correct and make sure that permissions allow users from network to access that file then may be it could work .

I recommend using a form instead of writing the file path manually then you can write your code like:

```
$file=$_FILES["userfile"]["name"];
$this->ftp->upload($file ,  './upload','ascii', 0775);
```